# SwiftUI's .confirmationAction the right choice to create something?

Tags: ios

I have the following situation in a View that is presented in a sheet,

[image]

The navigation part without the form field is basically

```
NavigationStack {
    .navigationTitle("Create event")
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
            Button("Add") {
                // todo
            }
        }
        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
            Button("Cancel") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm an old man and expect a "Submit" button at the bottom of each form. I even find myself shortly struggling in daily life when I wonder where the "Create" button is, especially when the form is longer.

My question is: from nowadays UX perspective, should there be a friendly "Create" button at the bottom of the form or is it OK the way it is, following Apple's "confirmationAction"?

By the way, if you have additional thoughts on how the sheet is done, feel free to tell/give feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe they are thinking that the user would read top left to bottom right in a zig-zag way?? - generally known as "Z visual hierarchy". But I agree with you that there is room for improvement to this - there could be better and more familiar CTAs for the form. Curious to know the Apple reasoning too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is essential to strike a balance between adhering to platform-specific design guidelines and maintaining usability for a diverse range of users. In your case, while Apple's "confirmationAction" follows the platform-specific design guidelines, adding a "Submit" or "Create" button at the bottom of the form can be beneficial for the following reasons:

- Familiarity: Many users, especially those who are not familiar with the latest design trends or platform-specific guidelines, expect to find a "Submit" or "Create" button at the bottom of a form. This can reduce cognitive load and make the interface more intuitive for them.
- Accessibility: For users with accessibility needs, having a clearly visible button at the bottom of the form can make it easier to interact with the interface.
- Long Forms: As you mentioned, when a form is longer, users might struggle to find the "Create" button if it's not at the bottom. Placing the button where users expect to find it can improve the overall user experience.

Given these reasons, it would be a good idea to include a "Create" button at the bottom of the form. However, you can still maintain the "confirmationAction" in the toolbar for users who are familiar with the platform-specific design guidelines. This way, you cater to a broader range of users while maintaining consistency with Apple's design recommendations.

As for the sheet design, it seems to be following the SwiftUI design pattern, which is a good practice. However, it's essential to test your design with real users to gather feedback and make any necessary improvements to enhance the user experience further.